# Rails: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that there are a lot of questions with the same error but i didn't find any that solves my problem. So, I have a "Bairro" and there are "Clientes" and "Imoveis" thats belongs to. The problem is that creating a customer "Cliente" works just fine, but when I go to create a "Imovel" I have the error: 

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass and highlight on:

```
<%= f.collection_select :bairro_id, @bairros, :id, :nome, {} , class: "form-control" %>
```

The Imovel.rb is like this:

```
class Imovel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bairro
  belongs_to :cliente
end
```

In the controller I have this:

```
def new
  @imovel = Imovel.new
  @bairros = Bairro.all
  @clientes = Cliente.all
end

def edit
  @bairros = Bairro.all 
  @clientes = Clientes.all 
end

def update
  @bairros = Bairro.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @imovel.update(imovel_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @imovel}
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end


def create
    @bairros = Bairro.all
    @imovel = Imovel.new(imovel_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @imovel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @imovel}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @imovel }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Usually this error happens when @bairros = Bairro.all is not defined, but not in this case.

The view opens just fine, I can edit to, but when I going to save, the error happens.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the error is because the form re-renders in your update action and you don't set `@bairros` there.

```
def update
  if object.save
    # works
  else 
    # doesn't work
    @bairros = Bairro.all # or something
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

or if you re-render the form anyway you can just to

```
def create
  @bairros = Bairro.all
  if ....
```

Comment: I the update method I have this:   def update
    @bairros = Bairro.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @imovel.update(imovel_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @imovel}  else
        format.html { render :edit }

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved put the @bairros = Bairro.all in the create method. Why I need to put that? In the Clientes controller i didn't have to.

Comment: You have to because the form is displayed through the `create` action on submitting, but `edit` action when viewed for the first time. And if the save fails, the form is re-rendered

Comment: You have to put this in the clients controller also if the save fails, maybe the save hasn't failed there?

Comment: I'm sorry about my answer I only understand what you mean after you edit your post and I want to make it clear for those who may have the same problem. On the clientes controller I didn't put that and its works just fine. I steel don't get why. Any way, thanks for the help I really appreciate.

Comment: Don't worry if you don't understand it, a lot of things in Rails take time to understand. Just stay with it and it will come. @SuBzer0